# Function that returns arbitrary decimal place on javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to make some function on javascript,
that receives some number and position number `n` and returns its `n`th decimal place.

That is,

```
nthdigit(3.5852,2) = 8
nthdigit(3.5852,3) = 5
nthdigit(3.5852,5) = 0
nthdigit(9.772,1) = 7
```

How can I do this correctly? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: @Tobias: One can only accept a single answer (and OP can't upvote yet), but it's totally fine to wait a few days before choosing the best answer. You can't expect accepts after 10 minutes!

Comment: @Bergi: Of course, I did not expect any answer to this question for the current moment. I had a look at his profile; no answers were accepted. That is why I asked him to start doing it in general. By the way, the pure math solution provided here is beautiful and deserves being accepted.

Comment: @Bergi I've tried using `parseInt()` before, but It didn't work, because `parseInt((5.3-5)*10)` was `parseInt(3.0000001)=3` but `parseInt((5.2-5)*10)` became `parseInt(1.99999)=1`, returning incorrect answers. Being  lucky, I found a great solution here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pure math solution:

```
function decimaldigit(num, n) {
return Math.floor(num * Math.pow(10, n)) % 10;
}
```

Comment: I always feel dumb when someone comes up with a pure math solution and i was suggesting string operations! Great!

Comment: @Merguez: It's not silly, as the pure math solution will be subject to floating point issues. Depending on what precision is expected, strings can be easier.

Comment: @Bergi If I even thought of the Math solution and then threw it away because of the issues you pointed out I would be glad :D.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the number to a String, split it on the decimal `.`, take the character you want and convert it back to a number.

```
function nthdigit(number, i) {
    var afterDecimal = number.toString().split(".")[1];
    return parseInt(afterDecimal.charAt(i-1));
}
```

I've chosen `charAt(i-1)` because character are counted starting `0` and it feels more natural in this case when you want the first number to put in `1`.

Answer (score 0):

This should be very easy to solve:

```
var nthdigit function(decimal, n)
{
    var dec = '' + decimal;                     //convert to string
    var decimalString = dec.split('.')[1];      //covert to array, take element with index [1]
    var decimalPlaces = decimalSting.split(''); //covert to array

    return parseInt(decimalPlaces( n-1 ));      //1. decimalPlace has index 0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another pure math solution, with better precision for high numbers and correct handling of negative numbers:

```
function nthdigit(num, n) {
    return n ? nthdigit((num % 1) * 10, n-1) : Math.trunc(num);
}
```

using [Math.trunc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/trunc):

```
if (typeof Math.trunc != "function")
    Math.trunc = function trunc(value) {
        return value === 0 ? value : !isFinite(value) ? value : value | 0;
    }
```